# ¿Cómo realizar esta validación de texto que solo admita letras y un espacio en C#?

Tags: c#

Tengo una pregunta, como se realiza esto? en C# eh intentado algo pero creo no esta bien.

[image: Problema]

```
 public string Nombre

        {
            get { return Datos[i].Nombre; }
            set
            {
                Datos[i].Nombre = value;
                foreach(char letra in Datos[i].Nombre)
                {
                    switch (letra)
                    {
                        case ' ': continue;                        
                    }                    
                }                
            }
        }
```

Comment: Pues, hay varias maneras: Puedes hacer un recorrido de todas las letras de la cadena de texto y tener contadores que van sumando cuando hay espacios, cuando hay caracteres ajenos a letras, y luego de ese ciclo, preguntar si el contador de caracteres ajenos a letras es mayor que cero. Cuando estás aprendiendo a programar, ignora lo que conoces del lenguaje de programación y enfócate en armar "bloques de lógica", cuando tienes la lógica funcionando tal y como quieres, puedes elegir cualquier lenguaje de programación para darle solución. PD: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour Saludos.

Comment: Te dejo un tip: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.char.isletter?view=net-7.0

Comment: using System.Text.RegularExpressions;  ...    if (new Regex("^(\\w)(?!.* {2,})(?!.*\\d).+$").IsMatch("value"))
            {
                Datos[i].Nombre = value;
            }